# PGP encrypt/decrypt in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage, pgp

I am in the process of moving applications to Azure using Azure Function Apps and Blob Storge. I’m trying to figure out a way to do Encrypting/Decrypting in Azure. When doing the same in our on-premise environment I used PGPCore package but that is when you can point to a local file. I’m struggling to figure out a way to do that in Azure Blob Storage. All examples seem to use local files.

Is see paid for apps like DidiSoft but I’m trying to stick with a free version if possible.

Currently I’m working on the decrypt side of things and the concept is that I will have a PGP file delivered to my Blob Storage. I have a Azure Function with a blob trigger looking for *.pgp files and that will call another Function App specifically for just PGP work. The idea is that the PGP Function App will, in this case, decrypt the file right back into the same blob storage but this time as a .txt file. I then have a blob trigger looking for .txt files and it will run code it needs to process that file. The .txt trigger is already done and working.  I already have my PGP function app calling Key Vault to get any Public/Private keys needed but what I’m not finding is a good way to do the actual Encrypt/Decrypt in Azure.

Anyone have any suggestions or examples to go look at?

Answer (score 0):

We follow a similar process: download a PGP file (SFTP in our case) and load it to Blob Storage. Then we call an Azure Function that uses [PgpCore](https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore) to Decrypt the PGP files in Blob Storage.

[image]

Here is the Decrypt code in the Azure Function:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PgpCore;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace AF_Services
{
    public static class PGPDecryptBlob
    {
        [FunctionName("PGPDecryptBlob")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function {nameof(PGPDecryptBlob)} processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            try
            {
                // Create TMP directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(IOHelper.TempAppDirectoryName);

                string sourceContainerName = data?.sourceContainerName;
                log.LogInformation($"Source container name: {sourceContainerName}");

                string sourceBlobName = data?.sourceBlobName;
                log.LogInformation($"Source blob name: {sourceBlobName}");

                string targetContainerName = data?.targetContainerName;
                log.LogInformation($"Target container name: {targetContainerName}");

                string targetBlobName = data?.targetBlobName;
                log.LogInformation($"Target blob name: {targetBlobName}");


                if (sourceContainerName == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Required parameter sourceContainerName not provided");
                if (sourceBlobName == null || targetContainerName == null || targetBlobName == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Required parameter sourceBlobName not provided");
                if (targetContainerName == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Required parameter targetContainerName not provided");
                if (targetBlobName == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Required parameter targetBlobName not provided");

                string keyBlobName = SettingsHelper.Get(Settings.PrivateKeyBlobName);
                string passPhrase = SettingsHelper.Get(Settings.PassPhrase);
                string blobAccountConnStr = SettingsHelper.Get(Settings.BlobConnectionString);

                // TMP file names
                var temp_sourceFileName = IOHelper.BuildTempFileName(BlobHelper.StripPath(sourceBlobName));
                var temp_targetFileName = IOHelper.BuildTempFileName(BlobHelper.StripPath(targetBlobName));
                var temp_keyFileName = IOHelper.BuildTempFileName(BlobHelper.StripPath(keyBlobName));

                // download Blob to TMP
                using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(temp_sourceFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var sourceBlobClient = new BlobClient(blobAccountConnStr, sourceContainerName, sourceBlobName);
                    await sourceBlobClient.DownloadToAsync(sourceStream);
                }

                // download key to TMP
                using (var keyStream = new FileStream(temp_keyFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var keyBlobClient = new BlobClient(blobAccountConnStr, sourceContainerName, keyBlobName);
                    await keyBlobClient.DownloadToAsync(keyStream);
                }


                // Decrypt
                using (var pgp = new PGP())
                {
                    using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(temp_sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (Stream outputFileStream = File.Create(temp_targetFileName))
                        {
                            using (Stream privateKeyStream = new FileStream(temp_keyFileName, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                await pgp.DecryptStreamAsync(inputFileStream, outputFileStream, privateKeyStream, passPhrase);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // write to target blob
                using (var decryptStream = new FileStream(temp_targetFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var targetBlobClient = new BlobClient(blobAccountConnStr, targetContainerName, targetBlobName);
                    await targetBlobClient.UploadAsync(decryptStream, true);

                    return new OkObjectResult(new { Status = "Decrypted", BlobInfo = targetBlobClient });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { RequestBody = data, Exception = ex });
            }
            finally
            {
                Directory.Delete(IOHelper.TempAppDirectoryName, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Encrypt code is similar, just in the opposite direction.

**UPDATE:**

The sourceContainer, sourceBlobName, targetContainer, and targetBlobName are passed in the JSON body of the Azure Function call.

The PrivateKeyBlobName, PassPhrase, and BlobConnectionString are stored in the Azure Function App's Settings.

The PGP work has to happen locally, so the IOHelper class (code below) is for working with the Azure Function's local file system.

```
public static class IOHelper
{
    private static string _TempAppDirectoryName;
    public static string TempAppDirectoryName
    {
        get 
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_TempAppDirectoryName))
            {
                var ts = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString();
                _TempAppDirectoryName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "{YourLocalDirectoryName}", ts);
            }
            return _TempAppDirectoryName;
        }
    }

    public static string BuildTempFileName(string fileName)
    {
        return Path.Combine(TempAppDirectoryName, fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'll try to implement your code. I'm also seeing where there are issues storing Private/Public keys in Key Vault and it removing line spaces which does look to be the case when I take a look at the returned value so I'll have to work through that one as well.

Comment: not sure what the best way is to ask a few questions about your code. I'm trying to implement it but struggling a little and it's probably due to my limited knowledge working with Azure. I would curious to see what your IOHelper.BuildTempFileName function is doing. I'm thinking it must be creating the full path to the Azure BlobStorage file?

Comment: I added some more information and code samples to the answer. We should be able to move this to a private chat, but I'm not sure how to do that on SO.

Comment: sent you a chat. Hopefully I sent it correctly since I've never done one either.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere

Comment: ....thanks for the help. I'm adding my code that I ended up using here in case someone else is looking to do the same.